# How to fix overwritted values in bar chart using matplotlib?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I want to plot a dataframe, using matplotlib, with values over bars, that way:

[image]

However, in my case, the values ​​are overwritten:

[image]

With that in mind, I have two doubts:

1. How to place the percentage value clearly over each bar?
2. How to put x-axis values, dates, horizontally?

My code:

```
  view = df_esc[['data_semana', 'porcentagem']].set_index('data_semana')
    del view.index.name

    ax = view.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(16,4),
                                            color="steelblue", fontsize=12)
    ax.set_alpha(0.8)
    ax.set_title("Porcentagem de professores que avaliaram", fontsize=18)
    ax.set_ylabel("% Professores", fontsize=12);
    ax.set_yticks(df_esc['porcentagem'].tolist())

    # create a list to collect the plt.patches data
    totals = []

    # find the values and append to list
    for i in ax.patches:
        totals.append(i.get_height())

    # set individual bar lables using above list
    total = sum(totals)

    # set individual bar lables using above list
    for i in ax.patches:
        for v in df_esc['porcentagem'].tolist(): 
            # get_x pulls left or right; get_height pushes up or down
            ax.text(i.get_x()+.12, i.get_height()-3, str(v) + 'str', fontsize=18, color='white')
```

I followed [this](http://robertmitchellv.com/blog-bar-chart-annotations-pandas-mpl.html) example.

Comment: The example you link to has one `for` loop. You are using 2 `for`-loops, hence you get several labels for each bar.

Comment: I have to iterate over ax.patches and my dataframe values. How can get my values once?

Comment: Yeah, do that in a single loop. You may read about `zip` if in doubt.

Comment: With zip I could fix my issue. Thank you!

Comment: Please don't answer your question within the question. A question should be a question. If you want to answer your question, press the answer button.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over the two loops, I used [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip)

**Solution**

```
view = df_esc[['data_semana', 'porcentagem']].set_index('data_semana')
del view.index.name

ax = view.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(16,4),
                                        color="steelblue", fontsize=12)
ax.set_alpha(0.8)
ax.set_title("Porcentagem de professores que avaliaram", fontsize=18)
ax.set_ylabel("% Professores", fontsize=12);
ax.set_yticks(df_esc['porcentagem'].tolist())

# create a list to collect the plt.patches data
totals = []

# find the values and append to list
for i in ax.patches:
    totals.append(i.get_height())

# set individual bar lables using above list
total = sum(totals)

# set individual bar lables using above list
for i, v in zip(ax.patches, df_esc['porcentagem'].tolist()):
    # get_x pulls left or right; get_height pushes up or down
    ax.text(i.get_x()+.14, i.get_height()+1, str(v) + '%', fontsize=12, color='gray')
```